# Handling NSLayoutConstraints from code properly

Tags: objective-c, autolayout

I started to use AutoLayout in my latest project, and I am stuck at some point. I use a content view controller, which adds other view controllers as sub view controllers, and their views as subviews aswell. Everything is fine, except that my sub controllers' view have wrong view sizes.

One of my sub view controllers sets up something like a slider, which has a knob. The initial position of this know depends from the actual size of this view, which is not fix, because I reuse it in many forms. Everything is set up with AutoLayout. Of course, because the value of this slider is coming from another part of code, the position of the know can be described only something like this:

```
self.knobVerticalPositionConstraint.constant = topPos + height * percentage;
```

where `height` is depending on the size of the slider view itself.

The problem is, that when the whole thing gets displayed, parts of my UI have wrong sizes. I even have a wrong view size in the sub controller's `-viewDidAppear`.

I think this is a problem of how I wrote my code. Maybe not everything is in it's place. I have read this article, which promises a clean and elegant way to solve this type of issues, but it is never revealed:

http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2013/06/ios-app-architecture-and-tdd-1.html

I have read the whole Internet, but I didn't found anything like this. It is full of stuff for beginners and first step guides about "How to use AutoLayout", but I never found any advanced tips.

So my specific question is: do you have any best practices, how to assemble a View Controller–View pair which uses AutoLayout from code? Where do you set up your constraints? Where do you update constraint constants like mine, which depends on the calculated values of the constraint equalation system? What code goes to the View and what to the controller? I'd be glad if you could share me some tips to solve this issue.

Comment: are you calling -updateConstraints on the view?

Comment: I call `self.progressWidth.constant = (1.0f-progress)*self.view.frame.size.width; [self.view layoutIfNeeded];` when updating my own progress view (a view which stretches from left-right not UIProgressView) in an animation block.  It might help if you could grab a screenshot of the other constraints (something might be overriding) and where in the code it's currently being set.

Comment: I do the same. My view architecture is very complex: I have a content controller, which has three sub view controllers (for left/right scrollable "pages") and one for a popup window. This popup is a content controller itself, because if has some kind of a wizard, with view controllers for each step. One of the steps if this slider.

Comment: without more code/images I'm kindof guessing as to what might be the issue.  Are you sure the code is actually being called? (i.e. set a breakpoint)

Comment: Yes it is called several times. It is currently in the `-updateViewConstraints` (is this the correct location for updating the constratint values?). It gets called even after `-viewDidAppear` runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently completed the migration of my first (and so far only) iOS project to Auto Layout. The stuff below is roughly what I have taken away from my efforts. It's not much, but since I wanted to write it down for myself anyway, here you go, maybe it helps.

- Static constraints that never change go into a view controller's `loadView` override, or in a view's initializer (or some sub-method thereof)
- Dynamic constraints which depend on other values calculated by the layout system go into a view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` override, or in a view's `layoutSubviews` override (in the latter case it makes sense to call `[super layoutSubviews]` first to get updated values that the dynamic constraint can be based on).
- After a change to a dynamic constraint, it may be necessary to tell the layout system that something changed. For instance, in a view's `layoutSubviews` override I call `[super layoutSubviews]` a second time after the constraint change so that the update is effective immediately
- A view controller can also override `updateViewConstraints`, and a view can override `updateConstraints`, but I have not used these so far.
- There are many other events that might trigger an update of dynamic constraints (e.g. keyboard events), but this is beyond the scope of best practices.

Some general guidelines:

- Constraints are installed by the view controller or view who sets up the view hierarchy and therefore knows about and is responsible for the layout of the view hierarchy. Although this rule is very basic, it sometimes pays to keep it in mind.
- The `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property of a UIView is set by that view controller which installs constraints for that UIView
- A view controller therefore does **not** set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property of its own root view. Instead, this is the responsibility of the parent view controller.

View controller properties related to bar handling in iOS 7:

- `edgesForExtendedLayout`, usually set to `UIRectEdgeNone`
- `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide`
- make all bars opaque (by default all bars are translucent in iOS 7), which would then allow the property `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to kick in

And some traps:

- Don't install constraints in `UIWindow`. When I tried this I had trouble when dismissing a VC after it was presented modally.
- The view controller properties `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` should only be used inside a view controller's override of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, and after they are used to install constraints one must invoke `[self.view layoutSubviews]`. This advice is actually from Apple's documentation of those two properties. Not following the advice may lead to weird layout issues (it happened to me).
- If a view controller's view hierarchy contains one or more scroll views (e.g. table views), and there are unexpected layout results, then the view controller property `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is probably playing a role. Setting it to `NO` might help.

My personal favourite ressource, by the way, for understanding Auto Layout was and still is [this section](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_order_of_layout_events) from the book "Programming iOS 6".